# Printing to UEFI Shell StdOut

Tags: uefi

As per UEFI Shell Specification,

```
EFI_SHELL_PARAMETERS_PROTOCOL
typedef struct _EFI_SHELL_PARAMETERS_PROTOCOL {
    CHAR16          **Argv;
    UINTN           Argc;
    EFI_FILE_HANDLE StdIn;
    EFI_FILE_HANDLE StdOut;
    EFI_FILE_HANDLE StdErr;
} EFI_SHELL_PARAMETERS_PROTOCOL;
```

> **StdOut** The file handle for the standard output for this executable.  This may be different from the ConOutHandle in the
> EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE.

I thought that maybe Shell's StdOut is a more preferred standard output for a shell application than `EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE.ConOut`. However, it seems that I cannot simply open the `EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL` on this handle as `OpenProtocol` throws `EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER` at me.

I tried opening the protocol with `StdOut` handle as the `Handle` and `ImageHandle` of the application as the `Agent`. `Attributes`: `EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_GET_PROTOCOL`.

`EFI_FILE_HANDLE` type of the `StdOut` param bothers me. Maybe the `EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL` is not installed on the handle? If so, what's the purpose of `StdOut` then. Or could it be a bug in the Shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFI_FILE_HANDLE is not the same as EFI_HANDLE, it is defined as:

```
typedef struct _EFI_FILE_PROTOCOL         *EFI_FILE_HANDLE;
```

You have to use the methods from EFI_FILE_PROTOCOL if you want to write to StdOut.